# Python 1 liners as arguments to functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to add another condition here:

```
fword.write(' '.join([chr(c-13+97) if c-13+97>96 else chr(c-3+48) for c in ground_valid])+'\n')
fword.write(' '.join([chr(c-13+97) if c-13+97>96 else chr(c-3+48) for c in output_valid]))
```

But I cannot quite understand the python 1 liners. From my understanding, if I expand it will be:

```
for c in ground_valid:
    if c-13+97>96:
        fword.write(' '.join(chr(c-13+97)))
    else if: # my condition
    # instructions
    else:
        fword.write(' '.join(chr(c-3+48)))
```

I tried just that but I don't get the expected output. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: add : after else

Comment: It was just my typo. I fixed it, but still if I do it as it is and run the script with the 1 liner and with the expanded version I get different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fword.write(' '.join([chr(c-13+97) if c-13+97>96 else chr(c-3+48) for c in ground_valid])+'\n')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
tmp_list = []
for c in ground_valid:
    if c-13+97>96:
        tmp_list.append(chr(c-13+97))
    else:
        tmp_list.append(chr(c-3+48))

tmp_str = ' '.join(tmp_list)
fword.write(tmp_str + '\n')
```

That is, `[<expression> for <variable> in <sequence>]` is a list comprehension that evaluates to a list - it's a shorthand form of `map` (the syntax also lets you `filter` as well, but that's not used in your example)

The expression in this case is `chr(c-13+97) if c-13+97>96 else chr(c-3+48)` which is the python format of a terniary operator. `<expression1> if <condition> else <expression2>` is equivelent to `<condition> ? <expression1> : <expression2>` in C, for example.

Your mistake is that you are calling join inside the loop, rather than constructing a list with the loop and calling join on the result.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the analogue of your two one-liners:

```
# fword.write(' '.join([chr(c-13+97) if c-13+97>96 else chr(c-3+48) for c in ground_valid])+'\n')
lst = []
for c in ground_valid:
    if c-13+97>96:
        lst.append(chr(c-13+97))
    else:
        lst.append(chr(c-3+48))
fword.write(' '.join(lst)+'\n')
```

and

```
# fword.write(' '.join([chr(c-13+97) if c-13+97>96 else chr(c-3+48) for c in output_valid]))
lst = []
for c in output_valid:
    if c-13+97>96:
        lst.append(chr(c-13+97))
    else:
        lst.append(chr(c-3+48))
fword.write(' '.join(lst))
```

Do you appreciate them more now?

---

An alternative, and more compact (and more readable imho) version of your one-liners would be the following:

```
choises = {True: -13+97, False: -3+48}
fword.write(' '.join([chr(c + choises[c-13+97>96]) for c in ground_valid])+'\n')
fword.write(' '.join([chr(c + choises[c-13+97>96]) for c in output_valid]))
```

*Having an `if-else` block without `elif`s should make you wonder if a dictionary would be better.*